# what is the regex for matching only #hashtags?

Tags: php, regex, regular-language

i am working on a social networking application and it have hash tag feature. i want to match all #tags but not #[[123:hashTag:rameez]] . i know reg-ex for both separately how can i do it in a single reg-ex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example :

```
$tweet = "this has a #hashtag a  #badhash-tag and a #goodhash_tag";

preg_match_all("/(#\w+)/", $tweet, $matches);

var_dump( $matches );
```

Comment: Why do you use a capture group?

Comment: @RameezRami no problem just put the question as resolved now